# Возможные значения для /configuration/startup/requiredRuntime/@version в .config файле?

Tags: windows, .net

Элемент requiredRuntime файла .config в атрибуте version определяет какую версию .NET runtime должно использовать приложение.
Где на заданном компьютере посмотреть возможные значения для атрибута version?

Comment: Вы имеет в виду список установленных версий .NET?

Comment: Я имею ввиду "возможные значения для атрибута version".

Comment: Но вы пишете «на заданном компьютере». Возможные значения атрибута не зависят от того, на каком компьютере вы их просматриваете.

Comment: [Документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5dzwzc9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) говорит _value must match the directory name found under the .NET Framework installation root_.

Comment: А вот по русски [документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/a5dzwzc9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Но есть документация, а есть практика.

Comment: На моей машине выглядит так: http://pastebin.com/t3Y6us6r То есть, возможные значения v1.0.3705, v1.1.4322, v2.0.50727, v3.0, v3.5, v4.0.30319.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что документация не соответствует действительности?

Comment: @Vlad документация соответствует действительности. Вопрос относится к практике, т.е. его суть в "Где на заданном компьютере посмотреть".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустимые значения - это именно имена папок из `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` или `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64`.

Вписать можно любое значение (по крайней мере любое в формате vX.Y.Z.Q), например `v10.0.0.0` или `v3.0.0.0`.

При запуске проверяется существование папки `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vX.Y.Z.Q` и файла `clr.dll` или `mscorwks.dll` в ней. Если файла нет - то показывается окно с предложением установить соответствующую версию. Если файл есть - то он и используется для старта приложения.

Т.е. если сделать копию папки `v4.0.30319` с именем `v10.0.0.0` и указать `requiredRuntime version="v10.0.0.0"` - то приложение стартует вполне корректно.

Comment: А ссылки на источники добавить можешь? Про mscorwks.dll я прочитал в книжке [XML.NET](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/8747667/), но она про .NET 2.0, причем, бету. Поэтому хотелось белее актуальные ссылки найти.

Comment: я в качестве источников испольовал Process Monitor. там прямо видно как приложение перебирает папки. потом подбросил то, что оно там ищет (один файл, потом всю папку) и посмотрел на результат.

Comment: механизим со времен .net 2.0 не сильно поменялся - requiredRuntime вводили во времена 1.0/1.1

Answer (score 0):

Это же опция компилятора, так что в его конфиге и нужно смотреть

Вот пара примеров:

\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\csc.exe.config

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" safemode="true"/>
        <requiredRuntime version="v2.0.50727" safemode="true"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe.config

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

---

PS: компилятора VB конфиг vbc.exe.config называется

Comment: Дополнение: на имена папок нельзя полагаться, так, например, в конфиге \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\csc.exe.config указана версия v2.0.50727

Comment: это не опция компилятора. это опция конкретного приложения.