# Как заставить сборку для runtime v2.0.50727 работать через COM с runtime v4.0?

Tags: .net, com

Есть сборка, которая скомпилирована для .NET runtime v2.0.50727.
Для одного из классов в реестре регистрируется COM параметры.
Таким образом мы можем использовать данную сборку через COM вызовы в каком-либо другом приложении, написанное на COM.

Как эту сборку заставить работать через COM с runtime v4.0?

P.S. Как заставить работать через EXE знаем от [сюда](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получается так.

При регистрации COM в InprocServer32 для RuntimeVersion нужно установить версию рантайма для .NET 4.0:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как определить какие версии рантайма сейчас установлены можно посмотреть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416491).